# function defined in module not global?

Tags: 7

I created a module in order to define a few functions that I would like to use from a workflow rule. The workflow rule is triggered by an event and runs a php code snippet. The php snippet that it runs is simply a function call to the function that I defined in my module.

However each time my rule executes the code, I see an error in the httpd error_log - `call to undefined function`. I ran the module through php lint, and I enabled it, flushed caches, and even restarted httpd for good measure. Still I get the error "`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function`" in the log.

I'm new to modules and Drupal programming so I must be missing something, but I thought functions defined in drupal modules (modulename.module) are global?

BTW I followed the instructions [here](http://www.bobbymods.com/faq/drupal-modules/how-do-i-add-my-own-php-functions-drupal).

Edit1: I defined my functions in module.module (not .inc...)

Comment: Have you checked that the module is enabled?

Comment: *defined in my module* - in .module or in .inc? (of course it only matters if it's enabled)

Comment: did you flush cache?

Comment: Yes it's enabled - I actually stated that in the question :)

Comment: @jdu yes I flushed cache - also mentioned in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually define my modules functions in a separate .inc file, and when i need them somewhere (usually sub-modules) i first include them with module_load_include( file-extension, module-name, file-path)

You can add the module_load_include() call at top of your snippet, or, if you need those function in many other places in your module hook_init() and make it avaible to every page.

Comment: I like this solution - I'd rather include the functions, run the function, and let them go out of scope and free up those resources. is it OK to have a blank .module and put all my functions in .inc then?

Comment: I think it worked! I move all functions from my .module into a new functions.inc and used module_load_include to pull in the .inc file and get to my functions. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can use a completely empty file for .module (it must exist though).

Comment: You can keep those function inside the .module file too, i have them in a dedicated file for the sake of order

Comment: @astrayus odd thing is when they were in the .module, I get `call to undefined function`, however when I moved them to the inc, used `module_load_include` .inc and then call the function, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes i meant, keep them in the .module, and use module_load_include('module', module-name, module-name)